# How do i use google apps script to modify data that i pull from google analytics?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-analytics-api

I'm using google apps script to pull data from google analytics and put it in a report in google sheets. For this specific report, the data pulled is very large and I want to modify it before I put it in the google sheet. I need your help to figure out how that can be done using javascript/google apps script.

This is my current code:

```
function testReport() {

  var profileId = XXXXXXX;
  var tableId = 'ga:' + profileId;

  var startDate = 'yesterday';
  var endDate = 'yesterday';  

  var metrics = 'ga:sessions';
  var optionalArgs = {  
    'dimensions': 'ga:landingPagePath, ga:date',
    'filters': 'ga:sessions>0',
  };

  var report = Analytics.Data.Ga.get(tableId, startDate, endDate, metrics, optionalArgs);

  if (report.rows) {

    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/FILLER_TEXT/edit#gid=0');
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Data'); 
    var firstEmptyRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1;

    sheet.getRange(firstEmptyRow,1, report.rows.length, report.rows[0].length).setValues(report.rows);
  }

}
```

`report.rows` is an object that is in this format:

```
[[/,20191228,100],[/locationOne,20191228,10],[/locationTwo,20191228,1],[/locationOne?s=a,20191228,10]]
```

This will create a google sheet that looks like this:

```
Landing Page        Date    Sessions
/                 20191228    100
/locationOne      20191228     10
/locationTwo      20191228      1
/locationOne?s=a  20191228     10
```

However, there are a lot of landing pages on my website so I need to condense this data before pasting it in the google sheet. Ideally, I want to do two things:

1. Create a new column called 'Web Section' based on Landing Page values. For example, if
   the landing page contains 'One' then the value in the new column
   should be 'Location One'. If the landing page contains 'Two' then the value should be 'Location Two'. If the value is not specified, all data should fall under 'Others'
2. Do a group by on the data so that the data is grouped by the columns 'Web Section' and 'Date' and shows the sum of sessions

Based on this, I should get a new table that looks like this:

```
Web Section      Date    Sessions
Location One   20191228     20
Location Two   20191228      1
Others         20191228    100
```

Thank you for helping me out with this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to achieve the following situation.

  - From

    ```
    [["/",20191228,100],["/locationOne",20191228,10],["/locationTwo",20191228,1],["/locationOne?s=a",20191228,10],["/locationOne",20191229,10]]
    ```
  - To

    ```
    Web Section      Date    Sessions
    Location One   20191228     20
    Location One   20191229     10
    Location Two   20191228      1
    Others         20191228    100
    ```
  - You want to modify `location` to `Location`.
  - If the date is different, you want to separate the date.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Flow:

The flow of this modified script is as follows.

1. Retrieve the value as `report` with `Analytics.Data.Ga.get()`.
2. Create object. This is used for calculating "Sessions".
3. Create array. This is used for putting to Spreadsheet.
4. Put the array to Spreadsheet.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

From:

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/FILLER_TEXT/edit#gid=0');
var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Data'); 
var firstEmptyRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1;

sheet.getRange(firstEmptyRow,1, report.rows.length, report.rows[0].length).setValues(report.rows);
```

To:

```
// Please set the key words for using as "Web Section".
var searchValues = ["One", "Two"];

// Create object.
var object = report.rows.reduce(function(o, e) {
  var idx = -1;
  var check = searchValues.some(function(f, j) {
    if (e[0].indexOf(f) != -1) {
      idx = j;
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  });
  if (check) {
    var s = searchValues[idx];
    var key = e[0].replace(/\//g, "").split(s).shift().replace(/^[a-z]/g, function(f) {return f.toUpperCase()}) + " " + s +  "_" + e[1];
    o[key] = key in o ? o[key] + Number(e[2]) : Number(e[2]);
  } else {
    var others = "Others_" + e[1];
    o[others] = others in o ? o[others] + Number(e[2]) : Number(e[2]);
  }
  return o;
}, {});

// Create array.
var array = Object.keys(object).map(function(e) {return e.split("_").concat(object[e])});
array.sort(function(a, b) {return (a[0] < b[0] ? -1 : 1)});

// Put array to Spreadsheet.
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/FILLER_TEXT/edit#gid=0');
var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Data'); 
var firstEmptyRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1;
sheet.getRange(firstEmptyRow,1, array.length, array[0].length).setValues(array);
```

#### For checking script:

```js
var report = {rows: [["/",20191228,100],["/locationOne",20191228,10],["/locationTwo",20191228,1],["/locationOne?s=a",20191228,10],["/locationOne",20191229,10]]};

// Please set the key words for using as "Web Section".
var searchValues = ["One", "Two"];

// Create object.
var object = report.rows.reduce(function(o, e) {
  var idx = -1;
  var check = searchValues.some(function(f, j) {
    if (e[0].indexOf(f) != -1) {
      idx = j;
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  });
  if (check) {
    var s = searchValues[idx];
    var key = e[0].replace(/\//g, "").split(s).shift().replace(/^[a-z]/g, function(f) {return f.toUpperCase()}) + " " + s +  "_" + e[1];
    o[key] = key in o ? o[key] + Number(e[2]) : Number(e[2]);
  } else {
    var others = "Others_" + e[1];
    o[others] = others in o ? o[others] + Number(e[2]) : Number(e[2]);
  }
  return o;
}, {});

// Create array.
var array = Object.keys(object).map(function(e) {return e.split("_").concat(object[e])});
array.sort(function(a, b) {return (a[0] < b[0] ? -1 : 1)});
 
console.log(array);
```

#### Note:

- In this modified script, in order to search the key words for using as "Web Section", I used `var searchValues = ["One", "Two"];`. Because I'm not sure the patterns of `locationOne`, `locationTwo`. So in this modified script, at first, please set this.
- Unfortunately, I'm not sure whether `20191228` and `100` of `["/",20191228,100]` are the number or the string. So I used `Number(e[2])` in the modified script.
- If you don't want to sort the array, please remove `array.sort(function(a, b) {return (a[0] < b[0] ? -1 : 1)});`.

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)
- [String.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)
- [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize. At that time, can you provide more sample values and output you expect? By this, I would like to confirm it.

### Added:

- You want to use `One`, `Two` as the search values.
- You want to use `First Output`, `Second Output` as the name which is used for putting the Spreadsheet.

About your additional question, I could understand like above. If my understanding is correct, how about the following sample script?

```
// Please set the key words and names for using as "Web Section".
var searchValues = {
  search: ["One", "Two"],
  name:   ["First Output", "Second Output"]
};

// Create object.
var object = report.rows.reduce(function(o, e) {
  var idx = -1;
  var check = searchValues.search.some(function(f, j) {
    if (e[0].indexOf(f) != -1) {
      idx = j;
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  });
  if (check) {
    var key = searchValues.name[idx] +  "_" + e[1];
    o[key] = key in o ? o[key] + Number(e[2]) : Number(e[2]);
  } else {
    var others = "Others_" + e[1];
    o[others] = others in o ? o[others] + Number(e[2]) : Number(e[2]);
  }
  return o;
}, {});

// Create array.
var array = Object.keys(object).map(function(e) {return e.split("_").concat(object[e])});
array.sort(function(a, b) {return (a[0] < b[0] ? -1 : 1)});

// Put array to Spreadsheet.
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/FILLER_TEXT/edit#gid=0');
var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Data'); 
var firstEmptyRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1;
sheet.getRange(firstEmptyRow,1, array.length, array[0].length).setValues(array);
```

- In this sample script, please correspond the index of `search` and the index of `name` in `searchValues`.
- In above case, the values searched with `One` and `Two` use the name of `First Output` and `Second Output`, respectively.

Comment: Wow thanks for this! I'm still trying to figure out what it does, but it works great. One question: if i want to define the output in the 'Web section' column so that instead of Location One / Location Two it will give me a specific string - how do i do that? 

For example, if the url in the landing page contains 'One' the output should be 'First Output'

Comment: @Abhay Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional question, although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about it, if you want to use `First Output` instead of `Location One` and `Location Two` as the identification, please modify `var searchValues = ["One", "Two"];` to `var searchValues = ["First Output"];`. If I misunderstood your additional question, I apologize.

Comment: I'm trying to change the value that will show up in the output. So, if `var searchValues = ["One", "Two"];` then the output value should be `First Output` and `Second Output` instead of `Location One` or `Location Two`. Essentially, I want to be able to define what the output string should be. Please let me know if that helps clarify the query!

Comment: @Abhay Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill and poor understanding. From your replying, I thought that I could understand about your additional question. So I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you want, I apologize again.

Comment: That's exactly what I need - thank you so much! Also, your English and programming skills are amazing - never apologize for them :)

Comment: @Abhay Thank you for replying and your comments. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure on your scope (if you only plan to do 4 LPs or if there's n LPs), but a simpler approach would be to create segments on GA for the LPs you want to pull. Then create a Google Sheet with GA add-in that pulls data from those segments.